_xsaveopt64 Usage in Kernel-Mode
I need to manage extended processor state using _xsaveopt64. My current approach with _fxsave64 and _fxrstor64 has been as follows:
alignas(16) char fxStateBuffer[512];

// Saving state
_fxsave64(fxStateBuffer);

// Restoring state
_fxrstor64(fxStateBuffer);

now, i need to transition to using _xsaveopt64 for optimized state management how should I initialize the buffer and manage the state saving and restoration process ?
